# SQL Join's from 3 Table based on two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I have following 3 tables: `Users`, `Friendship` & `Location`

I need to write query where by data is pulled from all 3 tables based on userid.

[image]

[image]

I think trick here is that you have to pull data based on two columns from friendship table i.e. userid and friendid (so both are each others friend) and based on which user's friends list you need, you need to pull his friends name,email and location accordingly.

I have written some queries using joins, but can't get what I need as mentioned above.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: hey is your question is same as mine ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015124/datatables-searching-at-server-side-php-mysql ..you got solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select f.id as friendshipid,
       f.userid,
       f.friendid,
       u.name,
       u.email,
       l.location
  from (select id, userid, friendid
          from friendship
        union all
        select id, friendid, userid
          from friendship) f
  left join location l
    on f.friendid = l.userid
  left join users u
    on f.friendid = u.id
 where f.userid = 2
```

You can see a fiddle test here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8eba4/13/0

I used an inline view that reverses the friendships table and connects back to the table itself with a union, that way the query sees friendships in both directions, since they are stored in only one direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response Brian. 
I have gone that far unfortunately this is not working for me.
If i feed  userid=1 above query work perfect. 
if i feed  userid=2 nothing is returned.

Comment: @Mr.Mubi I believe I've fixed it, please see new fiddle and sql.

Comment: @Brain once again thanks, i have already tried that. It will give same result for both userid=1 and 2. So basically 1st query work fine for userid=1 and 2nd query work for userid=2. I need query which work fine for both. or may be there is limitation and need to change the structure of db. But i was wondering if there was solution how friend list is saved in database. i don't feel appropriate to have 2 records for one friendship. as if user jim send request to jay and both are friends it should be save in a single record? any thoughts?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8eba4/19/0 is not the same as http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8eba4/13/0

Comment: Did you try my new query? It does work for both (see the difference between the 2 fiddles in my above content)

Comment: Awesome you are a STAR & a life saver. This one is working perfect. Thank  you very much!

Comment: Just a slight modification if there are more than one friends for Jim query was returning top 1 row, after changing both joins to left join its returning all friends.

Comment: Ah I see, I just edited the answer in case it's looked at in the future, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are only pulling one ID at a time, you can do this without doing subqueries.

```
SELECT friendship.id FriendshipID
, @SearchedID UserID
, users.id FriendID
, users.name Name
, users.email Email
, location.location Location
FROM friendship
INNER JOIN users
  ON friendship.userid = users.id 
  OR friendship.friendid = users.id
INNER JOIN location
  ON users.id = location.userid
WHERE 
  users.id <> @SearchedID
  AND (friendship.userid = @SearchedID OR friendship.friendid = @SearchedID);
```